# Rx Java Subscriber never gets onNext event from location updates

Tags: java, android, location, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to use this library: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3291 to get user's location. I did I think everything the sample shows but my Observable/Subscriber never triggers.

Here's my activity:

```
public class GpsActivity extends AppCompatActivity/* implements LocationListener*/ {

final android.location.Location[] lastKnown = new android.location.Location[2];
LocationManager manager;
boolean exitLoop = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.no_gps);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    getLocation();
}

private void getLocation() {
    //TODO zmienić UI
    boolean gpsPermission = checkPermissions();
    if (!gpsPermission) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "No GPS permissions!");

        //TODO Handle permissions result
        requestPemissions();
        return;
    }
    boolean gpsEnabled = checkSettings();
    if (!gpsEnabled) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "GPS not enabled!");

        //TODO Handle settings result
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        return;
    }
    subscribeForLocation(25f, this);

}

private void requestPemissions() {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Requesting permissions...");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, IntentHelper.PERMISSION_GPS);
    }

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Done.");

}

private boolean checkSettings() {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Checking settings...");
    return !manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

}

private boolean checkPermissions() {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Checking permissions...");
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Showing GPS settings alert...");

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), IntentHelper.GPS_SETTINGS);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}


public void subscribeForLocation(float accuracy, final Context context) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Subscribing for updates...");

    final LocationRequestBuilder locationRequestBuilder = new LocationRequestBuilder(this);

    locationRequestBuilder.addLastLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, new LocationTime(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS), false)
            .addRequestLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, new LocationTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .create().subscribe(new Subscriber<android.location.Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            saveLocation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(android.location.Location location) {
            final String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), location != null ? location.toString() : "Location is empty =(");
        }
    });
}
```

The output I get from my logs is this:

```
 D/GpsActivity: Checking permissions...
 D/GpsActivity: Checking settings...
 D/GpsActivity: Subscribing for updates...
```

And then it just sits there doing nothing. This is my first time using Rx so not really sure what I should do in this situation.

Comment: Can you check if `onCompleted()` is being called? On the first view, there is everything correct with your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you have wrong if statement - double negation.

```
boolean gpsEnabled = checkSettings();
if (!gpsEnabled) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "GPS not enabled!");

    //TODO Handle settings result
    buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    return;
}
```

Keep in mind that after subscribing you will receive only one result since observable will emit onCompleted after first received location because of the:

```
return result.firstOrDefault(defaultLocation)
            .observeOn(scheduler);
```

Notice that nothing will happen after user will grant permission because you are performing "return" from function if permission is not granted already. You can handle subscribing after granting permission by overriding following method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Depends on your needs you may want to be constantly notified about current location. One of the solution is to simply modified library that you are using (what is more preferable solution) and "fix" onCompleted event emitted by Observable. Another way is to subscribe every period of time:

```
Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .compose(this.<Long>bindToLifecycle()) //google rx trello github
        .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
               @Override
               public void call(Long aLong) {
                     subscribeForLocation(25f, GpsActivity.this);
               }
        });
```